# Boolean Method Confusion

Tags: java, methods, boolean

Hello there fellow programmers. Can someone explain to me what this piece of code does exactly? The starting method throws me off a bit (`isHigherThan(Card card2)`); other than that I'm fine. `card2` is not mentioned anywhere else in the java file.

```
public boolean isHigherThan(Card card2)
{
    boolean result = false;

    if (face == card2.getFace())
    {
        if (suit > card2.getSuit())
            result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (face > card2.getFace())
            result = true;
    }

    return result; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What part exactly don't you understand? Where the `card2` is coming from? It's just the passed-in method argument.

Comment: What type does getFace() method return?

Answer (score 3):

Probably, your `isHigherThan` method is implementd in the `Card` class which has at least the following properties: `face` and `suit`.

This method could be used like following:

```
Card card1 = new Card(/* whatever paremeters your constructor takes*/);
Card card2 = new Card(/* ... */);

boolean res = card1.isHigherThan(card2);
```

Now when you see just `face` or `suit` inside your method, this property is of the `card1`.
So when such `face == card2.getFace()` comparison are done, they basically compare `card1` `face` with `card2` `face`.

Answer (score 1):

`card2` is a parameter so it is only local to the method `isHigherThan` and that explains why you do not see it anywhere else in the file. The method you are looking at probably belongs to a class of type Card. When the method is called it first checks the face value of the cards to see if they are equal (queen == queen) then compare the suit (hearts vs diamonds) and set return value to true if the suit of `card2` is higher. The else statement means that the face values do not match (Jack & Ace) so if `card2` has a higher face value the result is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning `true` in two cases:

1. The method `getFace` of the given `Card` class returns value equal to some global variable called `face` and also the method `getSuit` of the same class instance is returning value smaller than global variable called `suit`.
2. The method `getFace` of the given `Card` class returns value smaller than global variable called `face`.

In any other case, the return value will be `false`.

The real use of this is to compare two instances of `Card` class: the one which its `isHigherThan` method is called with some other instance. If both cards have the same Face (number) then they're compared by the suit - Spades, Hearts, Clubs or Diamonds.

Answer (score 0):

isHigherThan is (probably) a method of the class card. It apparently returns true if the Card object upon which it is invoked has a value higher than the Card given as parameter.